# Do not post a query from running iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, database

I've been tormented. I can not understand why this code does not work? What did I do wrong? Thanks, I really need help

```
  <?php
$name = $POST['name'];
$tel = $POST['tel'];
$dbhost = "sql200.60ru.com"; 
$dbuser = "****"; 
$dbpassword = "***"; 
$dbname = "60ru_11939825_zav333"; 
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (name, tel) VALUES (" . $name . "," . $tel . ")";
mysql_query($query, $link);
 mysql_close($link);
?>
```

And

```
NSString *bodyData =  @"fio=GGG&telefon=2521521551277777";    
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zav333.60ru.com/test/insert.php"]];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:[bodyData length]]];
    self.mainUrl = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unvalidated, unfiltered user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$name = $POST['name'];
$tel = $POST['tel'];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
```

the right syntax for getting post value is `$_POST` not `$POST`and

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (name, tel) VALUES (" . $name . "," . $tel . ")";
mysql_query($query, $link);
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (name, tel) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $tel . "')";
mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```